# Is there a "best" forum for suggesting improvements to CiviCRM?

Tags: developer

As a developer, when I have an idea for a feature improvement to CiviCRM, and am interested in helping to make that happen (submitting a patch and tests, for example), what's the best place to start a conversation about things like a) whether it's a good idea, b) how it might be made into a better idea, c) whether it's likely to be desirable in core or better as an extension, etc.?

Channels I can think of include these, in no particular order:

- One of the lists at http://lists.civicrm.org/lists/
- One of the boards at forum.civicrm.org
- IRC (#civicrm on freenode)
- This StackExchange site.

**Edit:** I guess I'm wondering if there even is a definitive "best" forum for such discussions.

Comment: Another for the list is the new chat: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be useful to ask a self-serving question in SE and then answer it yourself. I think SE has a more public audience and hence improvements get noticed.

In addition, I would suggest starting off on one of the new chat.civicrm.org channels depending on whether it is 'hey i have this new idea' (maybe town square) or 'i need to insert x in to y while not breaking z' perhaps in the developer chat.

hth

Comment: Thanks Pete. I've edited the question to be more specific, namely: whether there's a generally accepted -- or better yet, an officially designated -- "best" forum for such discussions.